# How to Display 4week per month with condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have this logic but I cant figure out what to do to come up with the results. I want to achieve the results below, the idea is (Ex. month of October 2014), normally it has 5 weeks. If there is a 5th week and days is greater than 3 then consider whole week in  the next month else add it to 4th week.

```
  Input:
     date range

     from: 10-01-2014
     to:   11-30-2014  

  Sample Output:

     Date       Customer        week#          Dates covered
   10-01-2014     Cust01          1           Oct 01 - Oct 11, 2014
   10-08-2014     Cust02          1           Oct 01 - Oct 11, 2014
   10-17-2014     Cust02          2           Oct 12 - Oct 18, 2014 
   10-25-2014     Cust03          3           Oct 19 - Oct 25, 2014 
   10-31-2014     Cust01          4           Oct 26 - Oct 31, 2014
   11-01-2014     Cust01          1           Nov 01 - Nov 08, 2014
   11-28-2014     Cust02          4           Nov 23 - Nov 30, 2014
   11-30-2014     Cust05          4           Nov 23 - Nov 30, 2014

 Thanks
```

Comment: Your logic has problem when there are 6 weeks in a month such as Noverver 2014. Can you make an example output by November 2014?

Comment: In November's case, nov 1 will add to nov2-8 as week1 and nov 30 will be part of nov 23-29 as week 4.

Comment: So for a 28 days February starts from  Wednesday, you will want only 3 weeks?

Comment: No. Its a must that I need to display 4weeks in a month. So if 1st weeks is less than 4 days then it'll add to second week but still tag as week 1. Same as last week, if less than 4days then add to the previous week  and still tag as week 4. So there are cases that your week1 count as more than 7days as well as your week 4

Comment: Here's the problem. In October 2014 you have 4 days in the first week and 6 days in the last week and in your example you have combined the first week with the second and left the last week be. Now, in February 2017 the first week also has 4 days but the last one only 3. Would you still combine the first two weeks together or would you instead combine the last two weeks together? And there's more. In July 2014 both the first and the last week have 5 days each. Which of them would need to be combined with another week? Same for February 2012.

Comment: Oh, what if I have to choose  either ill add those days to previous week (4th week) or next week (2nd week). Like in July 2014, only add days in week 1 to week 2  then tag as week1 so that july 27-31 become week4. So im thinking that we need to count the weeks per month first then count the days of 1st week and last week then results will pass the 2nd condition?? any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Use `datepart(ww,[date])` to get week number in a year, then compare the week number by the begin date of a month.

Below is the detail approach to calculate for one date:

```
declare @dt date, @month_begin date, @month_end date, @week_of_month int
set @dt='20141031'
set @month_begin = convert(date,(convert(char(6),@dt,112)+'01'))
set @month_end = dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month,1,@month_begin))
set @week_of_month = datepart(ww,@dt) - datepart(ww,convert(date,(convert(char(6),@dt,112)+'01'))) + 1
select 
    case when @week_of_month > 4 and datepart(dw,@month_end)>3 
         then 1 
         else  @week_of_month 
    end as week,
    case when @week_of_month > 4 and datepart(dw,@month_end)>3 
         then datepart(month,dateadd(month,1,@dt))
         else datepart(month,@dt) 
    end as month
```